# open source IKE for Windows 7/8

Tags: ipsec, ike

Is there an open source implementation of Internet Key Exchange protocol for windows?
I found only openiked for linux platforms. (http://www.openiked.org/)

Comment: None that I'm aware of.  All IKE/IPSec open source implementations I can find are Linux based.  Might be a fun project to write the Windows daemon portion.  Fork OpenSwan and add a Windows side to it.  Most of the IKE protocol code is written so it might not be that terrible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[strongSwan](http://strongswan.org/) has been ported to Windows 7 / Server 2008 R2 and newer with its [5.2.0 release](https://wiki.strongswan.org/versions/52). It may be built using the MinGW toolchain (either on Windows or Linux) with a specialized set of plugins providing access to e.g. the Windows IPsec and networking stack. It also relies on the new [swanctl](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/swanctl) configuration and control interface (instead of the more commonly known `ipsec.conf` based configuration).

The [wiki page](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Windows) has more on this (including known limitations).